# Getting â€™ instead of an apostrophe(') in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, mojibake

I've tried converting the text to or from utf8, which didn't seem to help.

I'm getting:

```
"Itâ€™s Getting the Best of Me"
```

It should be:

```
"It’s Getting the Best of Me"
```

I'm getting this data from [this url.](http://www.tvrage.com/quickinfo.php?show=Surviver&ep=20x02&exact=0)

Comment: I see this sometimes when people IM or email me from a Mac.  Looking forward to seeing the solution.

Comment: Yeah im testing the code on a Mac too, using MAMP Pro.

Comment: If that came from a MySQL table, none of the fixes given here are appropriate.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To convert to HTML entities:

```
<?php
  echo mb_convert_encoding(
    file_get_contents('http://www.tvrage.com/quickinfo.php?show=Surviver&ep=20x02&exact=0'),
    "HTML-ENTITIES",
    "UTF-8"
  );
?>
```

See docs for [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) for more encoding options.

Comment: That works, though I can't figure out to get it to work on fopen

Comment: Once you get the contents of the file you want, then pass it in as the first parameter to `mb_convert_encoding()`. e.g., `$text = fgets($fp); $html = mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");`

Comment: domain is not valid anymore.

Comment: What about in a URL where the html entity wouldn't make a valid URL for something like an RSS feed.

Comment: @GreenGiant: My answer simply shows you how to convert from one encoding to another. URLs (excluding domains) can include Unicode characters; at least modern browsers know how to display them. e.g., this is a valid URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/. (Although SO is eating the slash after wiki.) So UTF-8 is generally an acceptable encoding for URLs. But if you wanted to avoid that, you could try using 'ASCII' for the second parameter. It obviously won't support as many characters though, so you may end up with '?' placeholders.

Answer (score 33):

Make sure your html header specifies utf8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

That usually does the trick for me (obviously if the content IS utf8).

You don't need to convert to html entities if you set the content-type.

Comment: This has got to be the greatest post ever! I updated my charset to utf-8 and it instantly fixed all my database driven pages. Thanks for that awesomely quick fix!

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer because it's a global solution.

Answer (score 12):

Your content is fine; the problem is with the headers the server is sending:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:502
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 18 Feb 2010 20:45:32 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=1, max=25
Server:Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.7 with Suhosin-Patch
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.7
```

Content-Type should be set to `Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`, because this page is not HTML and uses the utf-8 encoding. Chromium on Mac guesses ISO-8859-1 and displays the characters you're describing.

If you are not in control of the site, specify the encoding as UTF-8 to whatever function you use to retrieve the content. I'm not familiar enough with PHP to know how exactly.

Answer (score 10):

I know the question was answered but setting meta tag didn't help in my case and selected answer was not clear enough, so I wanted to provide simpler answer.

So to keep it simple, store string into a variable and process that like this

```
$TVrageGiberish = "Itâ€™s Getting the Best of Me";

$notGiberish = mb_convert_encoding($TVrageGiberish, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8');

echo $notGiberish;
```

Which should return what you wanted `It’s Getting the Best of Me`

If you are parsing something, you can perform conversion while assigning values to a variable like this, where `$TVrage` is array with all the values, XML in this example from a feed that has tag "Title" which may contain special characters such as `â€˜` or `â€™`.

```
$cleanedTitle = mb_convert_encoding($TVrage->title, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're here because you're experiencing issues with junk characters in your WordPress site, try this:

1. Open `wp-config.php`
2. Comment out `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8')` and `define('DB_COLLATE', '')`

   ```
   /** MySQL hostname */
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

   /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
   //define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

   /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
   //define('DB_COLLATE', '');
   ```

Comment: Don't do this on any live site - it has a high probability of blowing out any existing theme-related options. This answer also does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just try this

if `$text` contains strange charaters do this:

```
$mytext = mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8');
```

and you are done..

Answer (score 4):

if all seems not to work, this could be your best solution.

```
<?php
$content="Itâ€™s Getting the Best of Me";
$content = str_replace("â€™", "&#39;", $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

**==or==**

```
<?php
$content="Itâ€™s Getting the Best of Me";
$content = str_replace("â€™", "'", $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're using standard string functions on a UTF8 characters (’) that doesn't exist in [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1). Check that you are using [Unicode compatible](http://php.net/manual/en/book.unicode.php) PHP settings and functions. See also the [multibyte](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) string functions.

Answer (score 3):

We had success going the other direction using this:

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: this solved my problem, since utf8_encode alone was not working.

Comment: You are life saver.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
html_entity_decode(mb_convert_encoding(stripslashes($text), "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For `fopen` and `file_put_contents`, this will work:

```
str_replace("&rsquo;", "'", htmlspecialchars_decode(mb_convert_encoding($string_to_be_fixed, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should check encode encoding origin then try to convert to correct encode type.

In my case, I read csv files then import to db. Some files displays well some not. I check encoding and see that file with encoding ASCII displays well, other file with UTF-8 is broken. So I use following code to convert encoding:

```
if(mb_detect_encoding($content) == 'UTF-8') {
    $content = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $content);
    file_put_contents($file_path, $content);
} else {
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
    file_put_contents($file_path, $content);
}
```

After convert I push the content to file then process import to DB, now it displays well in front-end

Comment: I am having â€ instead of an apostrophe in Gmail title. And ASCII fix the problem. BTW, 1. charset is already set to UTF-8 and it did not work. 2. mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8'); turned out to be "&rsquo;" displayed in title. So this answer is the only fix for my case.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above solutions work:

In my case I noticed that the single quote was a different style of single quote.  Instead of ' my data had a ’.  Notice the difference in the single quote?  So I simply wrote a str_replace to replace it and it fixed the problem.  Probably not the most elegant solution but it got the job done.

```
$string= str_replace("’","'",$string);
```

Comment: Credit for targeting the most common of all culprits, the apostrophe lol

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the link, and it looks like UTF-8 to me. i.e., in Firefox, if you pick View, Character Encoding, UTF-8, it will appear correctly.

So, you just need to figure out how to get your PHP code to process that as UTF-8. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8_unicode_ci" />
```

instead of this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works try this mb_convert_encoding($elem->textContent, 'UTF-8', 'utf8mb4');

Comment: Welcome to SO, You might want to give some context as to why they should use that

Comment: In My case it worked with that code