# â€™s comes up instead of apostrophe ' in PHP

Tags: php, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting â€™ instead of an apostrophe(') in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292004/getting-a-instead-of-an-apostrophe-in-php)

I am new to the PHP programming language and I need some help. When writing to a file with PHP, when an apostrophe is written to the file, it actually writes â€™s. For example, when I try to write:

> Hello it's awesome

the program instead writes:

> Hello itâ€™ss awesome

I have tried multiple solutions, but still can't get it working. If somebody could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:
Ok so this is what i have tried:

echo mb_convert_encoding(
    file_get_contents($filename),
    "HTML-ENTITIES",
    "UTF-8"
  );

The result was: \"Hello\" instead of "Hello"

I have also tried:

$text = fgets($fp); 
$html = mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");

But didnt really understand what to do with that code

Also i would like to either convert a variable $stringDatad from â€™s characters or convert the whole file from â€™s characters. The file name is saved at $filename

Comment: Did you try `content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"` in your meta tag?

Comment: I just tried echo mb_convert_encoding(
    file_get_contents('http://www.tvrage.com/quickinfo.php?show=Surviver&ep=20x02&exact=0'),
    "HTML-ENTITIES",
    "UTF-8"
  ); But instead of a " i got a \"

Comment: How about you put up all your tries and their results in the question too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
echo stripslashes(mb_convert_encoding( file_get_contents($filename), "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8" ));
```

Comment: ok, so how would i save that to a variable and then overwrite the file ($filename) with that new unencoded file?

Comment: to assign to a variable just do:
$variable_to_write = stripslashes(mb_convert_encoding( file_get_contents($filename), "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8" ));
and then use one of the writing functions to write to the file:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php there are some examples there

Comment: ok so i used file_put_contents for that. So i get this error that says expected parameter 1 to be a string. This means that that second part (because parameter 0 would be first part) has to be a string? what if i want the second part to be $file_get_contects??

Comment: would be good to see the code just to make sure you havent missed anything out

Comment: ok my code is:  mb_convert_encoding(
    file_get_contents($filename),
    "HTML-ENTITIES",
    "UTF-8"
  );
 $variable_to_write = stripslashes(mb_convert_encoding( file_get_contents($filename), "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8" ));
// file_put_contents($ourFileHandle,$variable_to_write); I need the file to be overwritten, not add the new file to the end. That file_put_contents needs a string not a variable. How would i overwrite the file?

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!!!! YAY! I just used a simple replace script and that variable_to_write you gave me!! Thank you soooo much!! voting you UP!

Answer (score 0):

I think mb_convert_encoding takes $to/$from_encoding as parameters:
`mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');`

Is `HTML-ENTITIES` a valid value for the first parameter after the string?

Comment: I already have that in my code, sorry. It just changes those " s to \" which is another problem i am having

Comment: What's in the file? Can you post a few lines?