# BASH: Copy multiple files and show how long it takes

Tags: bash, time, copy, cp

I have a line in my bash script that goes like this:

```
cp -v /temp1/* /temp2/* >> $LOGFILE
```

$LOGFILE is basically that - a log file.  The result I currently get in the $LOGFILE is this:

```
â€˜/temp1/file1â€™ -> â€˜/temp2/file1â€™
â€˜/temp1/file2â€™ -> â€˜/temp2/file2â€™
â€˜/temp1/file3â€™ -> â€˜/temp2/file3â€™
â€˜/temp1/file4â€™ -> â€˜/temp2/file4â€™
```

First of all, I'd like to get rid of the prefix "â€˜" and trailing "â€˜".  Secondly, I'd either like to show the current time (in hh:mm format) or elapsed time so $LOGFILE will show:

```
10:24 /temp1/file1 -> /temp2/file1
10:27 /temp1/file2 -> /temp2/file2
```

or

```
00:03 /temp1/file1 -> /temp2/file1
00:27 /temp1/file2 -> /temp2/file2
```

Could someone please help me fix one or both these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to use a loop for this, and copy the files one by one, then print the date manually before each copy:

```
(for i in test1/*; do \
   printf "%s: " $(date +"%M:%S"); \
   cp -v $i ${i/test1/test2} | sed "s|[\`\']||g"; \
 done) >> log.file
```

The funny characters you are seeing are caused by your terminal's encoding.  They are the equivalents of ` and ', so the sed statement I provided should work (can't test locally as I don't have whatever encoding you are using).

**----- EDIT -----**

If you want to find **all** files under the directory (not just those directly in test1), you could use `find` with `-exec` as follows:

```
find test1 -type f -exec printf "%s: " $(date +"%M:%S") \; -exec echo {} \;
```

This will find all files, and run the two commands for each.  `{}` expands to the filename which was found.  The `\;` tells find that the command is done.   Do a `man find` for more info.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to modify your script's cp for subdirectories (such as `/dir1/test1`.  I will use your sed on the logfile to fix the encoding!

Comment: if you want to do all files, change the loop to read: `for i in $(find test1 -type f); do`.   This will iterate over all files, not just the ones directly under test1.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `â€˜` and `â€™` instead of ' or " is due to an encoding problem (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505733/718925)). What do you use to open $LOGFILE? Try with a `cat $LOGFILE`

You can use something like:

```
for fn in /temp1/*
do
    #hour and minutes
    d=$(date +%H:%M)
    # cp output
    c=$(cp -v $fn /temp2/)
    # echo
    echo $d $c >> $LOGFILE
done
```

Comment: As for the `â€˜`, at the end of my script is the following line  `/usr/bin/sendemail -f $EMAILFROM -t $EMAILTO -o message-file=$STATUSLOG -u $EMAILSUBJ -s $EMAILSMTP -a $EMAILATT`.  It is then opened in Outlook. In the actual logfile, it displays correctly as a `'`.

Comment: So, change the encoding in Outlook or replace the character in the script adding something like (as suggested in the other answer) `c=$(echo $c | sed "s|[\\`\']||g" -)`