# â€™ in PHP is converting to &rsquo; when using mb_convert_encoding in Outlook subject

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, outlook

I have a mail() function set up in PHP, when emailing to my email to test I noticed the subject was converting my ' into â€™.

```
$subject="Please provide an updated copy of your company's certification";
```

> result: Please provide an updated copy of your companyâ€™s certification.

I followed [Getting â€™ instead of an apostrophe(') in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292004/getting-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-instead-of-an-apostrophe-in-php) adding mb_convert_encoding but now I am getting &rsquo instead of '.

```
$subjectBad="Please provide an updated copy of your company's certification";
$subject= mb_convert_encoding($subjectBad, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8');
```

> result: Please provide an updated copy of your company&rsquo ;s certification.

It comes through fine to my personal email, so is there a way to properly display a ' in Outlooks subject or am I at the whim of whatever their system settings are?

Comment: Did you try [marking the content as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292004/getting-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-instead-of-an-apostrophe-in-php/2505733#2505733)? Also, I would recommend using [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) if you can, makes sending emails so much smoother and handles everything transparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you used to type the subject did not use a simple apostrophe `'` which has a common representation across virtually all single-byte encodings and UTF8, instead it used a "fancy" right single quote `’`, which is represented differently between single-byte encodings and UTF-8.

`mb_convert_encoding()` is converting to an HTML entity because you are literally telling it to, and email headers are not HTML so it's going to display as the literal string `&rsquo;`. The only character set other than UTF-8 that has "smart quotes" is Microsoft's cp1252, and that is still the wrong answer for email headers.

The simplest answer is: Don't do that. Use a normal apostrophe. Everyone hates dealing with "smart" quotes.

The more complex answer is that email headers *MUST* be 7-bit safe "ASCII" text, and anything else requires additional handwaving. Ideally you should be using a proper email library that handles this, and the dozens of other annoyances that will malform your emails and impact deliverability.

If you're dead-set on eroding your sanity and using `mail()` directly, then you're going to want to properly encode your subject line and use an explicitly-defined character set, [which you should be doing anyways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). Eg:

```
$subject = 'Please provide an updated copy of your company’s certification';

var_dump(
    sprintf('=?UTF-8?Q?%s?=', quoted_printable_encode($subject))
);
```

Output:

```
string(82) "=?UTF-8?Q?Please provide an updated copy of your company=E2=80=99s certification?="
```

Comment: You should use [`iconv_mime_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-encode.php) instead of using `quoted_printable_encode()` directly.